# why is jest not running my test correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to test my code using jest, so far I have this:

```
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    async function fetchThis() {
        try {
            if (something) {
                myFunction() // i am mocking this
            } else {
              somethingElse()
            }

        } catch (err) {
            setError(true)
        }
    }

useEffect(() => {
    fetchThis()
}, [])
```

I am mocking `myFunction` like so:

```
        myFunction.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            throw new Error()
        })
```

so it is successfully getting into the catch block

however for some reason it is never setting the `setError()` function to true

tests in jest:

```
        const { queryByText, getByText, getByTestId, rerender, debug, container } = render(
            <App {...props} />,
        )

rerender(<App {...props} />)
```

// I need to rerender apparently, some docs told me react doesn't run hooks in sync mode

any ideas why it wouldn't call this?

also to be clear, it is setting to `true` in the browser so it's definitely something with the tests.

this isn't even working when I do

```
useEffect(() => {
    setError(true)
}, [])
```

what the heck...

Comment: https://doppelmutzi.github.io/testing-custom-react-hooks/

Comment: you might need to use `act()` for updating the react state. https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act